# Evaluating the definite integral of the product of a random variable and its PDF over a subset of the support

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I evaluate the following: $$\int_{k_l}^{v_1}g_l(v)vdv-c\int_{k_{l}}^{v_{1}}g_l(v)dv$$ Where $g_l(v)$ is the pdf of random variable $v$, with support $[v_0,v_1].$ Both $k_l$ and $c$ are in $\mathbb{R}^+$. I know that the second term will evaluate to $G_l(v_1)-G_l(k_l)$, but I am not sure about the first. Thank you.

Comment: The second term can be expressed in a CDF. This is not the case for the first term. You can only evaluate it if $g_l(v)$ is known unto you. There is no general route here.

Comment: @drhab Understood, thank you.